# The list of containers could not be retrieved

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

When trying to view my containers in the dashboard, I get the following message in place of my containers view:

> The list of containers could not be retrieved. Try again later.

If the containers ever load and I click on one, I'm presented with a page with a never-ending loading wheel in the center and the page never loads.

Is there a stability issue with containers? Doesn't seem like anything is reported in the status page.

Comment: Please post your error message here (in text) instead of or in additiont to externally.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to inspect your container using command line? (cf ic inspect CONTAINER), What is the status of your container there?

Comment: Thank you for the reply Roger.  
My status is stuck in "Networking", and I have both a public & private IP for my container.  
I've also re-deployed my container and can now view it in my dashboard, but clicking the container brings me to a never-ending loading wheel.

Comment: Did you try stop and start it again?

Comment: I stopped & started and it still wouldn't load. I deleted my container and original image, re-deployed the image, and now get the following when attempting to view the container's page in Bluemix:

502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Roger. I stopped & started and it still wouldn't load. I deleted my container and original image, re-deployed the image, and now get the following when attempting to view the container's page in Bluemix:

502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared my cache, cookies, and deleted the container through CLI along with the registry and have been able to consistently view the UI now.

Now I'm encountering other issues where my container is automatically shutting down after a while. I'll investigate this further and create a new post if needed.